# Extending the string prototype for easily selecting elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually, I had done a small experiment few days before in **jquery@javaScript**. I modified the string prototype

I tried the following code. (Modified the String object prototype.)

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, '$', {
  get: function() {
    return $(this.toString());
  }
});
```

And now, when execute the following code, I get output: "Hi world";

```html
<div class="lab">
    Hello World
</div>
```

```
".lab".$.html("Hi World")
```

Actually my question is, is modifying the `String.prototype`, is it good?

I mean, does it hamper the performance of page. Because, until we access the '$' property/getter of initialized String object, it will not define the whole jQuery in String object every time it is initialized.

And rest of all I want to say is, this is my first post and I hope I have done good. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my answer. Actually instead of defining the whole jQuery in a String every time it is initilized, what I do is, 
Define a getter instead of property. 
It means, until we access the '$' property, the function (`jQuery.fn.init`) that executes the string is not really executed.

That is why, its safe and easy to select element this way.

No need to **worry**. I think I need to feedback this to **[John Resig](http://tel:jeresig@gmail.com)**. Or in his ***[website](https://johnresig.com/)***